# image inside of <a> makes the whole header clickable

Tags: html, css

I have an image inside anchor link and anchor is inside header. When I set the image size in pixels I can only click on image (as it should) but when I set image size as percentage the whole header becomes clickable. How can I prevent that?

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header a {
  display: flex;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header a img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

header button {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 34px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  margin-top: -16px;
}

header button svg {
  width: 9px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<header class="container">
  <a class="logo" href="index.html">
    <img width="10%" src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo">
  </a>
  <button>
            <svg element></svg>
        </button>
</header>
```

Comment: Check your html, you forgot to close svg tag

Comment: I purposely removed svg to make html shorter, it's not related to that.

Comment: make your img 100% and your a tag 10%

Comment: Thank you @norbekoff, it works, how did I even mess up with this silly mistake.